# Commit a single file to another branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch

I'm on branch `feature-x` doing some work, when I suddenly encounter an issue which should really be solved on another branch, `hotfix`.

I want to create a commit with that change, but on the `hotfix` branch.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944469/how-to-commit-my-current-changes-to-a-different-branch-in-git) I understand that the standard procedure would be to

```
# On branch feature-x
git stash
git checkout hotfix
git stash pop
git add -A
git commit -m "Fixed issue #562"
```

That would work if I didn't have many changes on branch `feature-x` already underway, which would throw a conflict with the branch `hotfix`. I want to avoid having to resolve unnecessary conflicts.

To avoid that, I was thinking that I could only extract a single file from the stash, as noted on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1105666/80766). So the procedure would be:

```
# On branch feature-x
git stash
git checkout hotfix
git checkout stash@{0} -- <src/buggyfile.xxx>
git add -A
git commit -m "Fixed issue #562"
```

And then I should go back to `feature-x`

```
git checkout feature-x
git stash pop
```

While [there's a way](http://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2009/02/25/git-tip-how-to-merge-specific-files-from-another-branch/) to *bring* files from another branch directly, I want to know if there's a way to *send* files to another branch, without all this hassle. **The actual modification is only a couple characters.**

Comment: If by "without all this hassle" you mean "without checking out `hotfix` and later `feature-x` again", then this question is a duplicate of [Commit a file to a Different Branch Without Checkout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933044/commit-a-file-to-a-different-branch-without-checkout). (You'll find some interesting answers, there, too. Whether any satisfactory ones, I dunno.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Commit a file to a Different Branch Without Checkout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933044/commit-a-file-to-a-different-branch-without-checkout)

Comment: I apologize for the vague language. I was more referring to less commands (without involving an alias).

Comment: From a practical point of view, the way to do this in modern (post-2.6) Git is with `git worktree add`, as I noted on the possible-duplicate question @das-g linked. The cherry-pick method Arpit describes will work but being able to open a separate Terminal or IDE window, move to a nominally-separate (but same underlying repository) work-tree, and work there, is convenient and cheap (takes only one checkout's worth of extra space). You can keep the hotfix work-tree around as long (or short) as you like.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can commit the change in `feature-x` and [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) it in `hotfix`, as follows:

```
# On branch feature-x
git add <file>
git commit -m "Fixed issue #562" // Note commit-id
git checkout hotfix
git cherry-pick <commit-id>
git push origin hotfix
```

Extending the answer as per @torek comment, to use [git-worktree](https://github.com/blog/2042-git-2-5-including-multiple-worktrees-and-triangular-workflows), as follows:

```
git worktree add -b hotfix ../hotfix origin/master
cd ../hotfix/
git add <file>
git commit -m "Fixed issue #562"
git push origin hotfix
```

Comment: I never used cherry-pick before. Would that *copy* or *move* the commit? Is the commit going to be on `feature-x` and `hotfix` at the same time?

Comment: It copy the commit and yes the commit will exist in both the branches at the same time.

Comment: You can then reset `feature-x` with `git reset HEAD^` after checking out that branch.

Answer (score 15):

To commit a file from `feature-x` to `hotfix`, there is an easy way to do that (assume the commit you just added on `feature-x` branch is `4712df727f7303bc95545d0f6a024129be97c5c2`):

```
# on branch hotfix
git checkout 4712d filename
git commit
```